# How to change inputs of the function given in theano.scan()?

Tags: theano, theano.scan

I have confusion about [theano.scan()](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html). I have read the official documentation but i still feel my knowledge is limited. I want to change the inputs of the function given in `theano.scan`. For example, i have the following code.

```
def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t1_prev, s_t2_prev):
    # i have my code here

[o, s, s2], updates = theano.scan(
            forward_prop_step,
            sequences=x,
            truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
            outputs_info=[None, 
                          dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim)),
                          dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim))])
```

So, here `theano.scan` runs over the sequence `x`. As far as i have understood, `forward_prop_step` gets input `x_t` when `theano.scan` goes through sequence `x` but how `forward_prop_step` gets the second and third parameter? Is `theano.scan` getting 2nd and 3rd parameter from the 2nd and 3rd value of the `outputs_info`?

If i want to modify the above code and want to give one more paramter x2 as a sequence to `theano.scan`, how should i modify the code? I want `theano.scan` to run over two sequences `x` and `x2` and give their values as the first two parameters (`x` and `x2`) of the `forward_prop_step` method. For example, prototype of `forward_prop_step` will be:

```
def forward_prop_step(x_t, x_f, s_t1_prev, s_t2_prev):
    # i have my code here
```

How can i change the above mentioned code on `theano.scan` to give both `x` and `x2` as sequence? Can anyone briefly explain how can i change paramters of the functions given to `theano.scan` and also the return values with examples?

**Few other questions**:

(1) If i am giving `n_steps` parameter along with `sequences` parameter, how `theano.scan` executes? Is `theano.scan` then works like a nested (two) for loop?

(2) How the parameter `non_sequences` is different from `sequences` in `theano.scan` function's parameter?

(3) Does `theano.scan` call the provided function for each element of the sequence parameter? If it does, then when I write a `print` statement inside the `forward_prop_step` function, the `print` statement executed only once though the computation inside the function executed for several times (gone through the entire sequence). How `theano.scan` repeatedly calls the method which provided to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `theano.scan` getting 2nd and 3rd parameter from the 2nd and 3rd value of the `outputs_info`?

-> Yes, if an element of `outputs_info` is not `None` it means it is a recurrent output and therefore has to be passed to the `step` function.

If i want to modify the above code and want to give one more paramter `x2` as a sequence to `theano.scan`, how should i modify the code?

-> You just need to include `x2` to the list of sequences

```
[o, s, s2], updates = theano.scan(
        forward_prop_step,
        sequences=[x, x2],
        truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
        outputs_info=[None, 
                      dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim)),
                      dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim))])
```

The order in which parameters appear in the `step` function is (elements of): `sequences`, `outputs_info` and `non_sequences` (only if they are specified in the `scan`).

(1) If i am giving n_steps parameter along with sequences parameter, how theano.scan executes? Is theano.scan then works like a nested (two) for loop?

If `n_steps` is provided `scan` will only iterate for these number of iterations. If you are iterating over a tensor whose 1st dimension has `10` elements and `n_steps` is `4` then scan will only iterate over first 4 'elements' of that tensor. It will not work like a nested loop.

(2) How the parameter non_sequences is different from sequences in theano.scan function's parameter?

`non_sequences` are not iterated upon by `scan`, they are only mentioned for clarity of code as they are used within the `step` function, obviously `scan` can figure out them on it's own and hence they are only optional, not mandatory (though recommended). Contrary, `sequences` specify the variables `scan` should iterate over as it loops.

(3) Does `theano.scan` call the provided function for each element of the sequence parameter? If it does, then when I write a `print` statement inside the `forward_prop_step` function, the `print` statement executed only once though the computation inside the function executed for several times (gone through the entire sequence). How `theano.scan` repeatedly calls the method which provided to it?

`theano.scan` iterates over first dimension of each elements within the `sequences[]` at once, and during each iteration it calls the `step` function. If you want to print intermediate computations inside `scan`, you should use `theano.printing.Print` (check [this](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/printing.html) link for details). The reason `print` statement gets executed only once is because the way Theano works is it builds a computation graph as it scans the code and afterwards only this computation graph is executed with the respective values, python's `print` cannot be part of made part of theano's computation graph and hence you see it only once.

I would suggest have a deeper look at the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/scan.html), and [this](https://github.com/mila-udem/summerschool2015/blob/master/scan_tutorial/scan_tutorial.ipynb) tutorial.

Comment: thank bro for your nice brief answer, i really appreciate it. I have added one more question (3rd question) to my post, can you please answer that too? I have read the documentation but couldn't understand how theano.scan iteratively calls the function?

Comment: I am glad, it helped